# Disable the console beep/bell under Illumos / Solaris?

Tags: solaris, opensolaris, illumos

When I login to the console of my Solaris box any command that would normally generate a bell (tab completion with more than one result, pressing an arrow key one too many times, etc) causes the physical system to beep. This is especially obnoxious because the beeps queue so a simple slip up (holding the left arrow too long) can cause it to keep beep for 5-10seconds because each bell needs to be heard.

Is there a simple way to disable this behavior in Solaris? I'm running OmniOS, but I imagine it applies equally to any version of Solaris or other Illumos based distributions (OpenIndiana, Nexenta, etc).

Comment: -vb is visible bell (flash) which supresses a beep - check the terminfo database in /usr/share/lib/terminfo for your TERM variable. Not all terminals support this.

Answer (score 3):

This has worked for me (OI 151a7 Intel).
Add this to /etc/system and reboot:

```
 * Disable system beep: modinfo | grep "beep"
 exclude: pit_beep
```